# win32: Get command-line behavior as in Linux

Tags: windows, winapi, console, stdout

On the different platforms, this is where an application's `stdout` will appear (I have marked the parts that I'm unhappy with):

#### If started from within a console window

- Linux: In the console window
- win32 "WinMain": **Nowhere**
- win32 "main": In the console window

#### If started by double-click on the desktop icon

- Linux: Nowhere
- win32 "WinMain": Nowhere
- win32 "main": A **new** console window is opened just for the application

I'm trying to build a mixed-mode application. Depending on the command-line arguments, it shall **either open a GUI, or behave as a command-line application**. This works fine on Linux, but on win32, I have to decide whether to make the whole thing "WinMain" or "main". No matter which I choose, one of the two modes is broken.

I have figured [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application) to hide a `main` application's console window, but this solution is less than ideal (if launched from an existing console, that console is hidden; if launched from a new console, that console flashes up before being hidden).

**Is there a set of win32 API calls that will make either "main" or "WinMain" mode behave the way that applications behave on Linux?**

Note that I also need to be able to process the application's stdout (if launched in command line application node through `CreateProcess`/`CreatePipe` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067156/1347646).

The language is `python3`, but I believe this hardly matters.

Comment: Maybe, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54536/2861476) could help you.

Comment: Use `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` and [AttachConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952.aspx) to determine, whether you should [AllocConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944.aspx) a new console window, or re-use the parent process' console.